# Flutter: Upload list to Firestore with different documentID

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I already make loop some function to save as a list to Firestore like below:

```
var documentAttachments = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('cs_candidates')
          .document(widget.userEntity.email)
          .collection('attachments')
          .document();

      for (FinalUrlModel data in result) {
        await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          await documentAttachments.setData(AttachmentsEntity(
            name: data.name,
            type: RESUME,
            urlName: data.url,
            url: AttachmentsHelper.validateUrl(data.url),
          ).toJson());
        });
      }
```

But when I try to save it and checked the data, the data that already saved it to Firestore only the last data. But actually I have 5 data as a list from `result`.

How to make different `documentID` so I can save all data without replaced the before data?
Or have any idea to save a list without looping first?

Because I need save all data list from `result` to Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are specifying `.document(widget.userEntity.email)` and `setData` will add the document at that reference. If you want different(random) `documentId` , don't pass anything in `document()`.That should work.

```
var documentAttachments = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('cs_candidates')
      .document()
      .collection('attachments')
      .document();
```

If you don't want random `documentId`, you can try appending some data at the end of `documentId` so it becomes unique.

Or you can use sub-collections

```
for (FinalUrlModel data in result) {
    await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      await documentAttachments.collection('some-collection').document().setData(AttachmentsEntity(
        name: data.name,
        type: RESUME,
        urlName: data.url,
        url: AttachmentsHelper.validateUrl(data.url),
      ).toJson());
    });
  }
```

I hope this helps!

Update:

Just move the `documentAttachments` inside a for loop like this:

```
for (FinalUrlModel data in result) {
        var documentAttachments = await Firestore.instance
            .collection('cs_candidates')
            .document(widget.userEntity.email)
            .collection('attachments')
            .document();

        await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          await documentAttachments.setData(AttachmentsEntity(
            name: data.name,
            type: RESUME,
            urlName: data.url,
            url: AttachmentsHelper.validateUrl(data.url),
          ).toJson());
        });
      }
```

So it will always generated `documentId` based on the number of lists.

Comment: But I need `.document(widget.userEntity.email)` to track this data is from user who. But I need random `documentID` after `.collection('attachments')`

Comment: Then maybe you can make sub-collections. `widget.userEntity.email` as first document and then sub-collection in that with random ids.

Comment: Can you update your code with `sub-collection`? So I will try it on my code

Comment: I think I don't need to create `sub-collection` because like you say, If I `don't pass anything in document()` like my last `document()` in my code already `don't pass anything`. But the problem why my `documentID` it's not build random again because I don't call it inside for loop. So I just move that to inside for loop and it's solved my problem